# Full local copy of an entire distro?

Tags: debian, scientific-linux

Any distro really, but I am first and foremost interested in Debianoids and Rheloids.

Once in a while I hear of someone who insists on keeping a full local copy of an entire distro. According to wikipedia, [Debian Jessie has more than 43000 packages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian#Release_timeline). Suppose I want a local copy of all of them, on a system with limited access to the internet and the Debian repositories. This cannot occupy more than a 100 GB (which is reasonably cheap by today's standards). How would I even proceed getting them, for a given stable release? I mean the entire dependency graph of all the packages a distro has been working on for a given release...[Scientific Linux/CentOS/RHEL have a dual layer "everything" DVD](http://ftp1.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/7x/x86_64/iso/), but it's less than 7 GB, so I doubt it's really "everything".

Answer (score 5):

You could mail-order a set of Debian DVDs, copy them to your hard disk and keep them up-to-date with `debmirror`.

Another variation on the same idea is to use a USB drive with enough space and `debmirror` at a location with good, fast, cheap internet access to do the initial mirror and then keep it updated with debmirror at your slow internet.  Or, get someone to do the initial mirror for you and mail it to you.

You can probably do similar things with rpm/yum repos, but I'm not as familiar with the tools.

Note that with limited internet access, you're probably better off using `apt-cacher-ng` than mirroring Debian.  Comment out the `deb-src` lines in your sources.list file(s) unless you actually need to download source packages.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but thought I'd add my two cents' worth. I do this with Scientific Linux using this command, run nightly:

```
rsync -avkSH --delete --delete-after --exclude=archive/debuginfo/ --exclude=archive/obsolete/ --exclude=SRPMS/ --exclude=i386/ --exclude=iso/ \
    rsync://rsync.scientificlinux.org/scientific/6.7/ \
    /home/dist/repo/scientific/6.7/ #> "$logfile" 2>&1
```

As you can see, I'm being somewhat selective, leaving out ISO images, source RPMs, and 32-bit executables I have no need for. The directory is currently 14 GB in size but they get bigger the further back you go, due to the increasing number of security fixes. For example, my 6.6 directory is 18 GB and my 6.5 directory is 31 GB.